# Checking username and password in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a username and password field and now i need to check and redirect him to the next page in Android.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         final EditText loginText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.widget44);
         final EditText loginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.widget47);
         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.widget48);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent myIntent = null;
                 if(loginText.getText().equals("admin") && 
loginPassword.getText().equals("admin")) {
                  System.out.println("Entering");
                  myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Page1.class);
                 } else {

                 }
                 startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
        }
```

Temp now i am checking by hardcoding the values, but this too does not work for me. Why? I usually check in **Java** like this, why does it not accept me the same way in Android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because `EditText#getText()` returns an `Editable` object. Try

```
if(loginText.getText().toString().equals("admin") && 
    loginPassword.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Now if have to check somewhere from DB, how do i proceed with... any ideas or examples out there.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need to put `toString()` to your textelements?
Like this:

```
if(loginText.getText().toString().equals("admin") && 
loginPassword.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
...
```

Edit: neutrino was faster (+1) :)

Answer (score 1):

I am finding only a small problem. In your code, correct it as shown below, and I think it will work:

```
if(loginText.getText().**toString()**.equals("admin") && 
    loginPassword.getText()**.toString()**.equals("admin")) {
    System.out.println("Entering");
    myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Page1.class);
} else {
    ...
}
```

See the correction in asterisks.