# When I click a button without giving the input, the app is closing immediately

Tags: android

```
unfortunatly this app has closed
```

This is seen when I press a button with out any input. and is there any way that I can read values. Need some suggestions to improve my code. there is also my xml file. By the way I'm a beginner.So kindly help me so that I can improve my coding skills.Sorry for such a lengthy post.[image]

```
package com.example.simplecalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  Button add,subtract,multiply,divide;
  EditText firstValue,secondValue;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    firstValue=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    secondValue=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            final int val1 =    Integer.parseInt(firstValue.getText().toString() );
            final int val2 = Integer.parseInt(secondValue.getText().toString() );
            TextView output= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
            output.setText(" "+(val1+val2));

}
});
subtract=(Button)findViewById(R.id.subtract);

subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
    final int val1 = Integer.parseInt( firstValue.getText().toString() );
    final int val2 = Integer.parseInt(secondValue.getText().toString() );
    TextView output= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    output.setText(" "+(val1-val2));

}
});
multiply=(Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
final float val1=Integer.parseInt(firstValue.getText().toString());
final float val2=Integer.parseInt(secondValue.getText().toString());
TextView output=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
output.setText(""+(val1*val2));
}
});
divide=(Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);
divide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
final float val1=Integer.parseInt(firstValue.getText().toString());
final float val2=Integer.parseInt(secondValue.getText().toString());
TextView output=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
output.setText(""+(val1/val2));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat output. My first guess, though, is that the call to `Integer.parseInt()` is throwing a `NumberFormatException` when it tries to parse an empty string.

Comment: Also note, in these cases generally start by monitoring the logcat output.  It may be accessible directly from the IDE, if you are using one.  From the command line, you can use `adb logcat`.  The exception information found in the log will typically help you identify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to parse an integer from an empty string. Modify your `onClick` methods to something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    if(firstValue.getText().toString().isEmpty() || 
            secondValue.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        return;

    final int val1 = Integer.parseInt(firstValue.getText().toString() );
    final int val2 = Integer.parseInt(secondValue.getText().toString() );
    TextView output= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    output.setText(" "+(val1-val2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me. But why should that blank space added in the output.setText(). And If I want to use System.out.println(), can I? sorry for that. as I'm a beginner I have many doubts in android. And also where is public static void main(String[] args){}. Execution will be started at this position right?

Comment: You should never use `System.out.println()` on Android, use Log instead: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/util/Log.html For your second question, you should really take a look at the life cycle statuses in android: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html Android uses Java, but does something a bit different at runtime. The starting point of the application is specified in your Android manifest.

Comment: I found android code here. And there he is using 'System.out.println()'. Can you explain me a bit about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780197/checking-username-and-password-in-android)

Comment: I don't know why he is doing it like that, but you should really use Log

Answer (score 2):

I think your **logcat** throws `Nullpointer Exception`.
So when you click button without proper validation it crashes .

So you need to add proper validation .use  **isEmpty()** to avoid this problem

Comment: Got it. And again I have a doubt. How can we handle exceptions in android. can we use the same try-catch block to handle exceptions

Comment: Yes yes..you can use try catch block like Java.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the EditTexts are empty before any operations. You can do it as follows

```
if(!firstValue.getText().toString().matches(""))
{
     //Enters if not empty
     //Perform operations here
}
```

For eg. your `add.setOnClickListener()` should be like

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(!firstValue.getText().toString().matches("") && !secondValue.getText().toString().matches(""))
            {
                 final int val1 =    Integer.parseInt(firstValue.getText().toString() );
                 final int val2 = Integer.parseInt(secondValue.getText().toString() );
                 TextView output= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
                 output.setText(" "+(val1+val2));
            }
        }
});
```